# Python- adding two functions together

Tags: python

Working on a problem set- here is the Q:

Two function definitions are saved in the same file:
A function count_vowels has one parameter, a word, and returns the number of vowels in that word.
A function count_consonants has one parameter, a word, and returns the number of consonants in that word.
To determine the number of letters in a word, write a one-line body for the following function that calls both count_vowels and count_consonants:

```
def count_letters(word):
""" (str) -> int

Return the number of letters in word.
>>> count_letters('hello')
5
>>> count_letters('bonjour')
7
"""
# Write the one-line function body that belongs here.
```

My answer:

```
return count_letters(count_vowels() + count_consonants())
```

Wrong. Why?

Comment: What do count_vowels or count_consonants return?

Comment: What's wrong with `count_vowels(foo) + count_consonants(foo)` without the `count_letters`?

Comment: @tcaswell Did you read the question?  It's pretty clear what they return if you read the question.

Comment: @SethMMorton Socratic method

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `count_letters`, just the other two functions.  You also need to pass the `word` argument to each function.

```
return count_vowels(word) + count_consonants(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that it should be just `count_vowels(string) +count_consonants(string)` instead?

Comment: You are missing the function arguments.

Comment: Obviously they didn't know, otherwise they wouldn't have asked.